# how to tell google to not use a DIV with product suggestions as the catalog-search resultt

Tags: search-engine-indexing

How to let google know, the content in a div is not the main content of this page?

abstract example of my catalog-page:

1. Users search for "sports car", my website displays "**sports cars**" images and titles.
2. Under the header at top of each page is a DIV with product suggestions as "popular-and-last-watched **car tuning products**" (not main content and should not be indexed by google with this URL.

Problem: Google loves the DIV with "popular-and-last-watched". at google search, someone searches for "car tuning product" and the google-search will show him/ link to the catalog-page of "sports-car". The car-tuning-product is not visible there, only sports cars.

Canonigal link for a single div?
data-no-snipppet? (not working)
Not a solution: javascript display:none and other "hide" concepts

```
<header>
<div id"**not** important car tuning products" > "other users bought this product" images + descriptions </div>
<div id="**important** sports cars" > "main content with products" images + descriptions</div>
```